# inserting rss feed images into mysql database with feedparser, MySQldb and python

Tags: python, mysql, rss, mysql-python, feedparser

i am able to parse an rss feed and save the links, tiles and description to my database successfully, however when i try to do the same for images in the same feed, i'm getting an error. I already checked if the xml file has the category 'image' to work with via:

> > > d.feed.image
> > >       {'subtitle': u'SABC News', 'links': [{'href': u'http://www.sabc.co.za/news/', 'type': u'text/html', 'rel': u'alternate'}], 'title': u'SABC News', 'height': 173, 'width': 308, 'title_detail': {'base': u'http://www.sabc.co.za/SABC/RSS/news/TopStoryRSSFeed.xml', 'type': u'text/plain', 'value': u'SABC News', 'language': None}, 'href': u'http://www.sabc.co.za/wps/PA_News/images/newslogo2.jpg', 'link': u'http://www.sabc.co.za/news/', 'subtitle_detail': {'base': u'http://www.sabc.co.za/SABC/RSS/news/TopStoryRSSFeed.xml', 'type': u'text/html', 'value': u'SABC News', 'language': None}}

but when i try to save it to my database, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/les/Desktop/rss2.py", line 18, in <module>
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO zed (title, description, link, image) VALUES    
(%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (d.entries[i].title, d.entries[i].description,   
d.entries[i].link, d.entries[i].image))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 416, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError, "object has no attribute '%s'" % key
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'image'
```

the code i'm using is the following:

```
import feedparser, MySQLdb
```

I set up connection to MySQL database

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='',db='rss')

cursor=db.cursor()
```

fetch feed and turn into feedparser object

```
d=feedparser.parse('http://www.sabc.co.za/SABC/RSS/news/TopStoryRSSFeed.xml')
```

determine number of entries in feed, which is used in processing loop

```
x = len(d.entries)
```

processing loop - for each entry, selects certain attributes and inserts them into a MySQL table. Also converts the RSS entry date into a MySQL date

```
for i in range(x):
    d2 = d.entries[i].description
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO zed (title, description, link, image)   
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (d.entries[i].title, d.entries[i].description,   
    d.entries[i].link, d.entries[i].image))

db.commit()
```

what could be he problem?

Comment: >>> print d.entries[0].keys()
['summary_detail', 'published_parsed', 'subcategory', 'links', 'title', 'tags', 'summary', 'guidislink', 'title_detail', 'link', 'source', 'published', 'id']

where is "image"?

Comment: @murali' is is not it?  href': u'http://www.sabc.co.za/wps/PA_News/images/newslogo2.jpg',

Comment: I think you should replace "d.entries[i].image" with "d.entries[i].links[1].href" and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace

```
d.entries[i].image
```

with

```
d.entries[i].links[1].href
```